# Why aren't the CPU core numbers in sensors output consecutive?

Tags: cpu, temperature, sensors

The core number is 0,4,8,.....39 in the `sensors` command.

Why not 0,1,2,3,4.....?

```
foo@foo-linux:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +73.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +46.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +50.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 8:        +52.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 12:       +47.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 16:       +73.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 20:       +50.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 24:       +58.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 28:       +52.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 36:       +48.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 37:       +48.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 38:       +48.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 39:       +48.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

**update again**

This is a 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12700

This is a PC, not a server, with only 1 CPU socket.

**update**

```
foo@foo-linux:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i apicid
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
apicid      : 8
initial apicid  : 8
apicid      : 9
initial apicid  : 9
apicid      : 16
initial apicid  : 16
apicid      : 17
initial apicid  : 17
apicid      : 24
initial apicid  : 24
apicid      : 25
initial apicid  : 25
apicid      : 32
initial apicid  : 32
apicid      : 33
initial apicid  : 33
apicid      : 40
initial apicid  : 40
apicid      : 41
initial apicid  : 41
apicid      : 48
initial apicid  : 48
apicid      : 49
initial apicid  : 49
apicid      : 56
initial apicid  : 56
apicid      : 57
initial apicid  : 57
apicid      : 72
initial apicid  : 72
apicid      : 74
initial apicid  : 74
apicid      : 76
initial apicid  : 76
apicid      : 78
initial apicid  : 78
```

Comment: Related: [Understanding core IDs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400615/86440).

Comment: The processor number in `/proc/cpuinfo` is consecutive.

Comment: update the command result in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core number comes from the `cpu_core_id` variable in the `struct temp_data` in the `coretemp` driver module. In its source code, `cpu_core_id` is described like this:

```
* @cpu_core_id: The CPU Core from which temperature values should be read
*       This value is passed as "id" field to rdmsr/wrmsr functions.
```

The `rdmsr` and `wrmsr` are machine code instructions to read/write Model-Specific Registers in the specified processor. The `coretemp` module uses these instructions through functions defined in [arch/x86/lib/msr-smp.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/lib/msr-smp.c?h=v6.2.8). These functions just pass the CPU/core ID field through as-is, so the IDs shown are exactly the IDs used by your motherboard and CPU(s).

If your motherboard had 4 CPU sockets with only one socket populated, the firmware might have configured to assign the ID numbers to each socket in turn, so the IDs that would belong to the empty sockets are just left unused. But in your case, there is a sequence of four contiguous core IDs at the end (36 .. 39), so this might be something different.

Maybe this is a single processor which has two types of cores, and one type of cores is numbered with gaps in the numbering (0, 4, 8 ...) and the other type with no gaps (36 .. 39)?

To know more, it would be necessary to identify the exact processor model (e.g. using the output of `lscpu | head -14`), and then study the technical documentation of that processor model to see how the core IDs are assigned at the hardware/microcode level.

If the motherboard/firmware cannot dictate the assignment of core IDs, then one could guess that the CPU manufacturer might be planning a next generation of processors with more cores of the first type (i.e. with the gaps in the numbering either partially or completely filled). But this is just a guess, and the manufacturer's plans might change anyway...

Answer (score 1):

This answer might not surprise you, but: because that's the way `sensors` was written.

`sensors` just uses `sensors_get_detected_chips` to walk through all the sensors there are – not through the CPU cores. And these order of the sensors is "as detected" on relevant buses (so, mainly I²C/SMBUS, emulated ISA), not in order of the (relatively arbitrary) numbering of CPU cores.

Comment: The question was not about separate sensor drivers, but about specifically how the `coretemp` driver gets its core IDs... but the answer is essentially the same: the IDs seem to be exactly what is used by the processor at the hardware/microcode level. One would have to study the technical documentation of that particular CPU model to know more.